# update every column according to one column data in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have created the query to insert data to my database table. now i want to know how to update that field according to email attribute

```
$user = User::create([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'address' => $request->address,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'user_role' => $roles,
        ]);
```

this is my insert query.i want something like(update every column where email="someemail")

i tried something like this,

```
$userupdate = User::fill([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
            'address' => $request->address,
            'phone' => $request->phone,
            'user_role' => $roles,
        ])->where('email',$request->email);
```

Comment: Did you check `update` and `where` function in laravel doc ?

Comment: Try to understand laravel use first, u r going wrong way

Comment: yes i did. its not saying how to do it with request method

Comment: @AkhtarMunir i'm new to laravel. stil learning

Comment: I will recommend you to see `Bitfumes` channel on YouTube for laravel best understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$userupdate = User::where('email',$request->email)->update([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    'address' => $request->address,
    'phone' => $request->phone,
    'user_role' => $roles,
]);
```

**Hope this will help you**

Comment: @PasinduSenarath Cheer .:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try some thing like this

```
$data = $request->all();

$userToUpdate = User::where('email', $request->email)->firstOrFail();

$userToUpdate->update($data);
```

*Note if your just wanting to update already created record you can just do

```
$userToUpdate->update($data);
```

Comment: He might not understand this because he is not picking up the laravel, he should clearify his knowledge first.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir, thats fair I just give him an idea of what it is he is trying to achieve

Comment: Yeah I have also recommended him a good channel to achieve from there which is not my channel